# How to deep link to nested stacks with react natvgation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to provide deep linking for my app by using React Navigation. Paths to top level navigation stack work fine but children paths of these don't.

My app uses a stack of React Native, redux, redux navigation and Expo. I've gone thru the docs on [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/) and [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html) on how to implement linking into the app. I've assigned the proper prefix and everything. I'm testing the app by using buttons that redirect to the desired paths and also by running 
`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/main"`

If I try to got to `/auth` or `/main` it works as expected. I see the app switching screens accordingly.

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/main

adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/auth
```

But when I try to go to a nested path, like `/main/events` nothing happens.

`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/main/events`

This is a simplified version of my routes but I'm actually using this exact code to run my tests.

```
AppNavigator = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
  // You could add another route here for authentication.
  // Read more at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html
  AuthLoading: {
    screen: AuthLoadingNavigator,
  },
  Main: {
    path: 'main',
    screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
      HomeStack: createStackNavigator({
        Home: {
          path: 'home',
          screen: HomeScreen,
          navigationOptions: () => ({
            title: 'Home',
            headerMode: 'none',
            headerBackTitle: null,
            headerBackTitleVisible: false,
            header: null,
          }),
        },
        EventsArchive: {
          path: 'events',
          screen: EventsArchiveScreen,
          navigationOptions: () => ({
            headerMode: 'screen',
            headerBackTitle: null,
          }),
        },
      })
    })
  },
  Auth: {
    path: 'auth',
    screen: AuthNavigator,
  },
}))
```

Comment: try like this. `adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/events`

Comment: That doesn't work either

Comment: I think `EventsArchive` path should be `main/events` @mixcas

Comment: Yeah, that's what it should be but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I was missing assigning a path to `HomeStack`. This is the working code:

```
AppNavigator = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
  // You could add another route here for authentication.
  // Read more at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html
  AuthLoading: {
    screen: AuthLoadingNavigator,
  },
  Main: {
    path: 'main',
    screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
      HomeStack: {
        path: '', // THIS IS THE PART THAT I WAS MISSING
        screen: createStackNavigator({
          Home: {
            path: 'home',
            screen: HomeScreen,
            navigationOptions: () => ({
              title: 'Home',
              headerMode: 'none',
              headerBackTitle: null,
              headerBackTitleVisible: false,
              header: null,
            }),
          },
          EventsArchive: {
            path: 'events',
            screen: EventsArchiveScreen,
            navigationOptions: () => ({
              headerMode: 'screen',
              headerBackTitle: null,
            }),
          },
        })
      },
    })
  },
  Auth: {
    path: 'auth',
    screen: AuthNavigator,
  },
}))
```